# Building a Bot in java

Tags: java, bots

I simply want to create an Bot that can run (preferably) on a web-server, and simply 'clicks' on an object of a web page using java.
please refer  me to some tutorials that can be of help to me

Comment: What kind of tutorial? Java? HTTP? "Web page objects"? What have you done so far? Do you have an actual question?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense but you could take a look at the AWT [`Robot`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.

Comment: Howard ,i need tutorial on how to build a bot in java.i am familiar with java but what kind of stuff is required to build a webot using java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can start from [Apache Droids project](http://incubator.apache.org/droids/). They have [module for web crawling](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DROIDS/droids-crawler)

Answer (score 3):

HtmlUnit is a programmable web browser (in Java). See http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html.

Answer (score 0):

Since a "click" is basically just a machine requesting a resource, you could do something as simple as:

```
clickURL = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(URLOrFilename).openStream()));
```

This will open the stream. I don't know if you have to actually read anything (e.g. `BufferedReader.readLine()`), or if you can immediately close the stream, but that'll do it. Wrap it in a `main()` method, and you're done.

You'll need to import the appropriate I/O Java libraries.